# DialogFlow, keep assistant open after completing action

Tags: javascript, action, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am having a problem when testing my Google Assistant app (made in DialogFlow). Every time I run the first intent and satisfy the criteria to run the corresponding action, the assistant ends and doesn't allow the user to input a value that may trigger the follow-up intent. The microphone is closed every time instead of continuing the conversation.

Is there a way to set up intents and corresponding webhook to ensure the app doesn't close itself every time a single action is completed?

```js
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';
const App = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// x. start custom code
const orderLists = [
  {
    reference: '0',
    clothing: ['shirt', 'top', 'bra'],
    deliveryStatus: 'will be delivered before 1pm, make sure youre in!'
  },
  {
    reference: '1',
    clothing: ['shirt', 'top', 'bra'],
    deliveryStatus: 'is due for delivery on February 2nd.'
  },
  {
    reference: '2',
    clothing: ['shirt', 'top', 'bra'],
    deliveryStatus: 'is due for delivery on February 3rd.'
  },
  {
    reference: '3',
    clothing: ['shirt', 'top', 'bra'],
    deliveryStatus: 'was delivered today at 2pm to your default address.'
  },
  {
    reference: '4',
    clothing: ['shirt', 'top', 'bra'],
    deliveryStatus: 'was left with your neighbour at 22 Waltham Drive, today at 2pm.'
  }
]


// a. the action name from the make_name Dialogflow intent
// const NAME_ACTION = 'make_name';
const NAME_ACTION = 'query_order';
const NAME_ACTION2 = 'query_order.query_order-more';
// b. the parameters that are parsed from the make_name intent
// const COLOR_ARGUMENT = 'color';
// const NUMBER_ARGUMENT = 'number';
const ORDERNUMBER_ARGUMENT = 'number';

const min = 0;
const max = 10;

exports.sillyNameMaker = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new App({request, response});
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));


// c. The function that generates the silly name
  function queryOrder (app) {
    let number = app.getArgument(ORDERNUMBER_ARGUMENT);
    app.tell('Order number '+ number + ', ' + orderLists[number].deliveryStatus) + 'Would you like to know more?';
  }
  function queryOrderItems (app) {
    let number = app.getArgument(ORDERNUMBER_ARGUMENT);
    app.tell('Order number '+ number + ', ' + orderLists[number].clothing);
  }
  // d. build an action map, which maps intent names to functions
  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(NAME_ACTION, queryOrder);

  let actionMap2 = new Map();
  actionMap2.set(NAME_ACTION2, queryOrderItems);

app.handleRequest(actionMap);
app.handleRequest(actionMap2);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that, in each case, you're using `app.tell()` to send the message back to the user. This not only sends the message, *but tells the Assistant that the conversation is over* and to close the microphone.

If you wish to continue the conversation (keep the microphone open and wait for a reply from the user), you should use `app.ask()` instead.

So your `queryOrder()` method might look something like this:

```
  function queryOrder (app) {
    let number = app.getArgument(ORDERNUMBER_ARGUMENT);
    app.ask('Order number '+ number + ', ' + orderLists[number].deliveryStatus) + 'Would you like to know more?';
  }
```

(As an aside - asking "Would you like more?" was very good practice in this case. Never leave the microphone open without prompting the user for what is expected.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I had a feeling it would be something as simple as syntax. Is it ok to reference several functions in the same file? Or are they handled separately? Thanks +1

Comment: Dialogflow doesn't care how you organize your code - as long as you handle the request and send a response. (If you have further questions along this line - please ask them as another question.)